# Complicated Indefinite Integration

Tags: integration

$\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}+2\right)^2}{3\sqrt{x}}\;\mathrm{d}x} =\frac{2}{3}\big(\sqrt{x}+2\big) $
I do not know how to get $\dfrac{2}{3}$. I assume $\sqrt{x}+2 = u$, then $\mathrm{d}u= \dfrac{1}{2}\,x^{1/2}$

But it is wrong answer....

So help me

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean $\int \frac{(\sqrt{x}+2)^2}{3\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: Please, format and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $\displaystyle \int \frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+2\right)^2}{3\sqrt{x}}\,dx$:

Let $\,u=\sqrt{x}+2\,$ and $\,du=\dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Thus, we now have $$\dfrac{2}{3} \int u^2 \,du=\dfrac{2u^3}{9}+C=\dfrac{2\left(\sqrt{x}+2\right)^3}{9}+C$$

Comment: No problem! You may want to consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark. Glad I could help!